# create function on the fly

Tags: php, function

I have a loader class for all my sites I create.

I use it to load things out of a assets folder.

eg I call `load::js('jsname');` to load the jsname.js file from

/assets/js

my question is,

is it possible to create arbitrary functions so I could create a new folder called

/assets/random

I could then call `load::random('randomname');` without actually having to create the `random` function?

Comment: You can't create named functions or methods in PHP runtime unless you use `eval()`, however you might get somewhere with [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [`__call()` and `__callStatic()`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) magic methods.

Example:

```
class Load {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        return "/assets/{$name}/{$arguments[0]}";
    }
}
```

Calling

```
Load::random("randomname");
```

will return the string

```
"/assets/random/randomname"
```

`__callStatic()` is available from php 5.3, `__call()` from php 5.

Comment: hmm, callStatic seems to be exactly what I need :)

Comment: although one other question, is __callStatic only called when the function name does not already exists? eg, if there is a function called random, what will it do?

Comment: A PHP <= 5.2 solution (although not magical) would be:
`abstract class load {
 private static $base_dir = 'includes/';
 
 public function load($directory, $filename){
  $directory = rtrim($directory, '/').'/';
  
  require_once(load::$base_dir.$directory.$filename)
 }
};`

Comment: `__callStatic` is only called if the method is not already defined, so if there is a method called `random()`, that will get called, if not, `__callStatic` will be fired

Comment: @Hailwood you are right, __callStatic() is called only when invoking a not accessible method in a static context. If a static method called "random" exists, it will be called and __callStatic will not be executed.

Comment: `__callStatic` can be used to write "ai code" or "code that writes itself", quite an interesting concept.